# App looking for Word 2007 as dependency, doesn't work with only Word 2010 installed

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, dde

I have an old app I'm running and one of its functions is generating reports. Now, the thing is, whenever I want to generate a report, the app creates an RTF file and tries to find Word 2007 to open it.

I have installed both Word 2010 and Word 2007 for testing the issue.

If Word 2007 set as default for opening documents, the app generates reports without issues. 
If Word 2010 is set as default for opening documents, the app gives the following error message: "Word.Document.8 is not registered as a DDE application. Please reinstall the application that opens this type of file."

Even with the error, the app creates the report in its install folder and I can open it with Word 2010.

I don't really want to use Word 2007 so is there a way to redirect the application to Word 2010? Maybe apply a registry fix? I don't mind having Word 2007 installed but I'd like to use Word 2010.

Many thanks for any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for a solution that makes the registry point at Word 2010's executable when an app calls Word 2007.